# How to open file with .tda .tdz extension ? and what kind of file is it?

Tags: c#

I need to open files with `.tda`, `.tda.tdz` extension and convert the data to readable string.

This is not Palm, I'm sure. Already tried that.

I think they are `IBM DB2` database temporary files.

In the same folder with these files I have a config file that says `.tda` files are Zip Compressed.

I'm .net c# developer, so I wanted to know if it is possible to do that in c#

Thanks.

Comment: Is this perhaps some custom type of tar/gz packing? The title.tda file you uploaded is 21K of all 0's. A Google search on [db2 tda files] reveals some potentially useful information.

Comment: I tried to Decompress it with ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib but nothing..

Comment: @nonacc, Any solution you come up with? I need to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These files are part of a dictionary. Oxford, Cambridge, Longman, and many other digital dictionaries use these files to store the dictionary data.

My guess is that they belong to some proprietary format that the publisher (**Pearson Education Limited**) uses, probably not related to DB2 at all.

For example, the "Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English 5" installation contains the

```
/ldoce5.data/fs.skn/files.skn/CONTENT.tda.tdz       <--
/ldoce5.data/fs.skn/files.skn/files.dat
/ldoce5.data/fs.skn/files.skn/TITLE.tda             <--
/ldoce5.data/fs.skn/files.skn/NAME.tda
/ldoce5.data/fs.skn/files.skn/TEXTTITLE.tda
/ldoce5.data/fs.skn/files.skn/CONTENT.tda
```

Besides copyright violations, dumping the strings in these files would probably require heavy reverse engineering. Most of them are probably just indexes of other parts of the dictionary data, and it's quite probably that the publisher took measures such as encryption against accessing the content as plain text.

Comment: So there is no way to decrypt these files? or maybe try reverse engineering? there's a chance to access the content as plain text?

Comment: It's always possible, but it seems it would be both illegal and very difficult.

Comment: Where should I start? Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I like how OP is not deterred by *two* mentions of this violating copyright. =)

Comment: @J.Steen Just reversing the files and extracting the strings is probably not a copyright violation(Depending on the reasons for doing it). Distributing the extracted strings is.

Comment: @CodesInChaos that depends on the jurisdiction (DMCA, etc.). But I really doubt this post or my answer could help other SO users in the future anyway.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Okay. *Possibly* violating copyright. =D

Comment: So how can i reverse these files and extract the strings? What I need to use? where should I start? I need a direction.

Comment: This project includes python source code that can extract all data from tda files: https://github.com/ciscorn/ldoce5viewer